# smarter way relevel column containing alphanumerical date in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

so for data below, I am looking for a neat way to help R understand Dec 2009 should come before Jan 2022 and so on. I can achieve this by releving the factor column maually. but is there another way in case I have a broad range of date.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(date = c("Jan-2010", "Feb-2010", "Mar-2010", "Apr-2010" ,"Dec-2009"),
                 value = c(2,1,4,3, 2))
df %>%

  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=date,
                y=value),
            group=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubridate is great for these types of issues. We can use lubridate's ym function:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date = c("Jan-2010", "Feb-2010",
 "Mar-2010", "Apr-2010" ,"Dec-2009"), value = c(2,1,4,3, 2))
df$date <- lubridate::my(df$date)
df %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=date,
                y=value),
            group=1)+
    scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %Y")
```

[image]

Comment: if using `lubridate` you do not have to use `gsub`

Comment: nice x label is not exactly what data set shows. years are missing. in case you want to edit it for future users

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
df %>%
  mutate(date = zoo::as.yearmon(date, "%b-%Y")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=date,
                y=value),
            group=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = df$date)
```

[image]

Comment: How Dec-2009 is missed here?